# Two forms on one page causes wrong validation

Tags: html, forms

I have one page with two separate forms. Most input fields are `required`. When I click the submit button on the second form, it asks me to fill out the `required` fields in the first form.

How do I make sure that it only validates the form in which I clicked the submit button?

```html
 <form method="post" action="index.php" name="orderQuick" id="orderQuick">
 <input type="text" name="street" id="street" required>
 <button type="submit" name="submitBtn" id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
 </form>

 <form method="post" action="index.php" name="order" id="order">
 <input type="text" name="street2" id="street2" required>
 <button type="submit" name="submitBtn2" id="submitBtn2">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: I've loaded both forms through two different templates in Mustache (php). Could that affect things? Because when I add the code above to JSFiddler, it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because you have not closed `<button>` tag so it is considering both input type in one `form`. Close `<button>` tag.I think it will solve your issue.

Comment: Sorry, I missed adding that in my example above. I have closed them, but the issue still persist.

Comment: I missed a </form> in my code. That was the issue.

What a bizarre fail... =)

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to use the jqueryvalidation plugin: (http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/)

Using this plugin, on the click of the respective submit buttons, you just need to call the method:

```
$("#orderQuick").valid();
```

and

```
$("#order").valid();
```

This should solve your issue.

Comment: Okey! So I need to use jquery or javascript? No way around it by just using HTML5?

Comment: Yeah, you will need to using jquery. If you use HTML5, and both of the forms will be validated.